# Combining .txt files in R using a loop

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to use R to combine dozens of .txt files into one single .txt file. Attached below is the code that I've been experimenting with so far. The files that I'm trying to combine have very similar names, for example: "e20171ny0001000.txt" and "e20171ct0001000.txt". As you can see, the only difference in the file names are the different state abbreviations. This is why I've been trying to use a for loop, in order to try to go through all the state abbreviations.

```
setwd("/Users/tim/Downloads/All_Geographies")

statelist = c('ak','al','ar','az','ca','co','ct','dc','de','fl','ga','hi','ia','id','il','in','ks','ky','la','ma','md','me','mi','mn','mo','ms','mt','nc','nd','ne','nh','nj','nm','nv','ny','oh','ok','or','pa','ri','sc','sd','tn','tx','ut','va','vt','wa','wi','wv','wy')

for (i in statelist){
  file_names <- list.files(getwd())
  file_names <- file_names[grepl(paste0("e20171", i, "0001000.txt"),file_names)]
  files <- lapply(file_names, read.csv, header=F, stringsAsFactors = F)
  files <- do.call(rbind,files)
}

write.table(files, file = "RandomFile.txt", sep="\t")
```

When I run the code, there isn't a specific error that pops up. Instead the entire code runs and nothing happens. I feel like my code is missing something that is preventing it from running correctly.

Comment: You might as well benefit from a solution for a related problem here:   https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-December/297456.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to create a list to update.  In the OP's code,`files` is a `list` of `data.frame` that gets updated in the `for` loop.  Instead, the output needss to be stored in a `list`.  For this, we can create a `list` of NULL 'out' and then assign the output to each element of 'out'

```
out <- vector('list', length(statelist))
for (i in seq_along(statelist)){
  file_names <- list.files(getwd())
  file_names <- file_names[grepl(paste0("e20171", statelist[i], 
              "0001000.txt"),file_names)]
  files <-  lapply(file_names, read.csv, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   out[[i]] <- do.call(rbind, files)


  }
```

As `out` is a `list` of `data.frame`, we need to loop over the `list` and then write it back to file

```
newfilenames <- paste0(statelist, "_new", ".txt")
lapply(seq_along(out), function(i) write.table(out[[i]],
      file = newfilenames[i], quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I already upvoted your answer but it isn't publicly displayed. If you don't mind, how would you convert 'out' to a .txt file? I'm trying to use the write.table() function without much success right now.

Comment: @TimApple24. Regarding writing to file.  The `out` is a list of `data.frames`